# Has the possibility of the return of organisms along with mined asteroid products to Earth been considered or discussed

Tags: asteroid, astrobiology, mining

Is it possible that mining on asteroids could bring life back to Earth such as bacteria?

Comment: Anything is possible. I'm not sure it's possible to answer this question.

Comment: A better way to write this question would be "Has the possibility of the return of organisms along with mined asteroid products to Earth been considered or discussed?" That way you don't ask for opinions, and answers can be factual and sourced (if it has been).

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, we don't know if or how possible it is. There have been many attempts to figure out if there is other life out there in the universe, one of the largest I'm aware of being SETI. However, it is worth noting that none of these have found anything yet. There are theories about things we've observed suggesting there might be aliens:

- A rock found in Antarctica from Mars with a potential fossilized bacteria.
- WOW signal (might be called something else but was an observed signal from SETI)
- Strange  light intensity signal from a star (KIC 8462852 / Tabby's Star)

There are many others but these were the most credible in recent times. Note that the scientific community ultimately determined that none of these were aliens. So to answer your original question, yes it's technically possible but incredibly improbable. It's something that is so negligibly low, that it basically won't happen as far as we're aware.

Comment: KIC 8462852 / Tabby's Star is the name for the Alien Megastructure.